# Duplicate installation of docker from both iso and apt

Tags: docker, ubuntu

### question

A virtual machine of mine is ubuntu, docker is installed when install ubuntu from iso. After that, I installed again from apt, because previous one is not registered in "systemctl". Now , there is `two space for both docker`, just like following.

1. Two docker have their own space for "docker ps / image CMD" .
2. Reboot start with "SPACE docker A", and "systemctl status" works good. Once "systemctl restart", move to "SPACE docker B".
3. If I want remove "SPACE docker A". How can I do it? I would be very grateful if any suggestion is given.
4. For now, my workaround is `manually systemctl restart` every time.

### appendix

```
root@wzhjworkmachine:~/gitRoot# echo "now I reboot"
now I reboot
root@wzhjworkmachine:~/gitRoot# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-24 04:12:19 UTC; 1min 10s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 941 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 11
     Memory: 118.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─941 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.395653457Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.395739427Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.395827870Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.396046259Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.631892982Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option -->
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.666930410Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.719311959Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=afacb8b7f0 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.8
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.720376021Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 24 04:12:19 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[941]: time="2020-08-24T04:12:19.752861257Z" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
root@wzhjworkmachine:~/gitRoot# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@wzhjworkmachine:~/gitRoot# docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
wzhjv001                                                 v1                  0127641f0d76        2 days ago          867MB
hub.ark.jd.com/wzhj-compile-image4jenkins/quickcompile   gov1.14             0127641f0d76        2 days ago          867MB
root@wzhjworkmachine:~/gitRoot# systemctl restart docker
root@wzhjworkmachine:~/gitRoot# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-24 04:13:45 UTC; 6s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 2103 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 12
     Memory: 38.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─2103 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.183475793Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.183480494Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.183485240Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.183615822Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.269534194Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option ->
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.303140798Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.313875267Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=afacb8b7f0 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.8
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.314078704Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine dockerd[2103]: time="2020-08-24T04:13:45.326129124Z" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Aug 24 04:13:45 wzhjworkmachine systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
root@wzhjworkmachine:~/gitRoot# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
1d09c0866672        9f266d35e02c        "/bin/bash"         About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                       intelligent_rhodes
root@wzhjworkmachine:~/gitRoot# docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
centos              7.4.1708            9f266d35e02c        17 months ago       197MB
```